# iPhone: how to interact programmatically with the native Calendar application

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, eventkit

Is there any way to interact with the native Calendar application without using `EventKit` or `EventKitUI`?  `EventKit/EventKitUI` lets you add/edit/delete etc. events in your native calendar, but I'm trying to find some way to add events to the native calendar so that when a user views an entry added thusly (viewed from the Calendar application, not from my application) by clicking on it, they see the item in a ViewController provided by my application (which has one or more extra buttons).

Is this possible, or do I have to emulate the entire native calendar inside my own application in order to get the calendar to behave the way I want it to?

Answer (score 3):

Judging from the quarantine-like protection of other built in apps, I'd bet this is impossible. I'm only 99,9% percent sure, though.

Comment: @Toaster: I'm at a similar percentage on this one (99.9% in my part of the world). :)